# How to stop infinity loop inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I need to convert class component into functional component,
When I convert it, it gave me an infinity loop. How can I stop this loop?

Class component ComponentDidMount code

```
componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(this.moveSnake, this.state.speed);
  document.onkeydown = this.onKeyDown;
}
```

Functinal component I wrote for above ComponentDidMount

```
useEffect(()=>{
  document.onkeydown = onKeyDown
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    moveSnake()
   }, 200);
   return () => clearInterval(interval);
},[]);



const moveSnake = ()=>{
  let dots = [...snake];
  let head = dots[dots.length-1];

  switch(direction){
    case "RIGHT":
      head = [head[0]+2, head[1]];
      break;
    case "LEFT":
      head = [head[0]-2, head[1]];
      break;
    case "UP":
      head = [head[0], head[1]-2];
      break;
    case "DOWN":
      head = [head[0], head[1]+2];
      break;
  }

  dots.push(head);
  dots.shift();

  setSnake(dots);
  console.log(dots);
}
```

Comment: Please share the code of the function you run inside the `setInterval`

Comment: @SinanYaman Sure I will update with it

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. Can you create a `codesandbox` reproduction of this bug, it will be easier to fix. Right now the problem isn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a line that never runs, after the return in the `useEffect`:

```js
document.onkeydown = onKeyDown;
```

Comment: I changed it to top of function. It runs now.

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a comment.

Comment: I agree @SinanYaman, but i cannot write comments.

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't remember about that limitation.